# Encontrar Relacionamento entre tabelas Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Gostaria de saber se é possivel encontrar as tabelas e os campos envolvidos em um relacionamento no oracle, uma query que retornaria uma tabela como:

> Table_Name, Column Name, Table_References
>
> Funcionario,id_Cargo,Cargos

onde a tabela Funcionarios possui um campo chamado ID_Cargo e eu gostaria de saber de qual tabela vem esse campo? encontrando assim o relacionamento completo

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que já temos a solução do seu problema aqui mesmo no stack overflow dê uma olhada:

[List of foreign keys and the tables they reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729996/list-of-foreign-keys-and-the-tables-they-reference)

Comment: Olá Raphael, quando usar referências, tente responder e não deixar apenas o link... mesmo sendo a resposta de um site da rede... [veja mais aqui sobre referências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Certo Melissa depois irei editar, muito obrigado pelo retorno!